# Get X and Y axes values from the mouse position in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I need to get X and Y coordinate values from the mouse location inside SVG. I created an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2RIm9KeCETDlrLIQz7U?p=preview). For `mousemove` function I want x and y coordinate position printed (scaled according to the data values from the mouse position). I tried using the invert function - but that doesn't work either. Can someone please help me to figure out how to get x and y coordinate values from mouse position? I am using d3 version 3.

```
  svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  console.log("x", d3.mouse(this)[0]);
  console.log("y", d3.mouse(this)[1]);
  console.log("x - using invert", xscale.invert(d3.event.pageX));
  console.log("y- using invert", yscale.invert(d3.event.pageY));
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, use `d3.mouse` instead of `d3.event.pageX` or `pageY`.

But the biggest problem is that you're setting the listener to the whole SVG and expecting to see the values according to the domain in the axes. That's not the adequate approach. However, if you want to stick with that, you have to **add the translate values** for those axes. In this case, 50 and 10:

```
console.log("x - using invert", xscale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0] - 50));
console.log("y- using invert", yscale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1] - 10));
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var width = 400,
  height = 500;

var data = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)


var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
  .range([0, width - 100]);

var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
  .range([height / 2, 0]);

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  console.log("x - using invert", xscale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0] - 50));
  console.log("y- using invert", yscale.invert(d3.mouse(this)[1] - 10));
});

var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xscale).orient("bottom");

var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yscale).orient("left");;

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
  .call(y_axis);

var xAxisTranslate = height / 2 + 10;

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate + ")")
  .call(x_axis)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

line {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What would be the right approach?

Comment: You should set the translate in the scale's range.

Comment: How to get the correct value of the cursor after increasing / decreasing?

Comment: @doox911 I'm not sure what you mean... the correct value of the cursor relative to a given container node is `d3.mouse(container)`, be the container translated or not.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, yes, but after the zoomed, coordinates are not correct, how to take into account the zoom?

Comment: d3.mouse has been now deprecated since d3.js  v6. Use d3.pointer instead : https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#pointer